# Go is still showing old version

Tags: go

I have installed go on my ubuntu machine following this guide here https://medium.com/@patdhlk/how-to-install-go-1-9-1-on-ubuntu-16-04-ee64c073cd79

However, when I do go version I am getting this still

go version go1.2.1 linux/amd64

I tried to do an apt-get remove go but it didnt work.

What should I do now

Comment: Try doing `which go` and make sure it's the one in your `/usr/local` directory, if not then it's because you've not removed the previous version.

Comment: `find / -name go`

Comment: It is simple: Use the installation instruction from golang.org. Not some random blog post.

Answer (score 2):

Try Purge command and re-install GO.

```
sudo apt-get purge golang*
```

even if this doesn't work try

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go
```